# SQL: Dynamic Order BY for Currency Colum using column number

Tags: sql, t-sql

We have a dynamic query in database as following and we are passing column Number to sort a data but it is not working properly due to some number format and currency.

Following is our example query.

```
 Select * from (
SELECT 
dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT(SUM(pcptlc.Value),'N')) AS [Planned] 
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT((REPLACE(REPLACE([Committed],',',''),'$','') - SUM(pcptlc.Value)),'N')) AS [To Be Planned]   
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT(SUM(pcptla.Value),'N')) AS [Actual]   
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT((REPLACE(REPLACE([Committed],',',''),'$','') - SUM(pcptla.Value)),'N')) AS [Remaining] 
from XPV.MyFIlterView d1 
) as FilteredView
ORDER BY cast(replace(3,'$','') as float)
```

We want to do order by using column number for above query but it not working it works using column name, can you please suggest way.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, amazing! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Why store formatted data in the first place? I think you need to have a CASE WHEN in your ORDER BY on column number so you can perform custom formatting pre column

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Select * from (
SELECT 
dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT(SUM(pcptlc.Value),'N')) AS [Planned] 
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT((REPLACE(REPLACE([Committed],',',''),'$','') - SUM(pcptlc.Value)),'N')) AS [To Be Planned]   
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT(SUM(pcptla.Value),'N')) AS [Actual]   
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT((REPLACE(REPLACE([Committed],',',''),'$','') - SUM(pcptla.Value)),'N')) AS [Remaining] 
from XPV.MyFIlterView d1 
) as FilteredView
ORDER BY 1,4 DESC
```

You can also use with clouse

```
WITH FilteredView AS (
SELECT 
dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT(SUM(pcptlc.Value),'N')) AS [Planned] 
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT((REPLACE(REPLACE([Committed],',',''),'$','') - SUM(pcptlc.Value)),'N')) AS [To Be Planned]   
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT(SUM(pcptla.Value),'N')) AS [Actual]   
,dbo.FormatAmountforCustomQuery(FORMAT((REPLACE(REPLACE([Committed],',',''),'$','') - SUM(pcptla.Value)),'N')) AS [Remaining] 
from XPV.MyFIlterView d1 
)



SELECT * FROM FilteredView
ORDER BY 1,4 DESC
```